# Обращения по алиасу в MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Сразу попрошу не закидать меня улыбками, запрос очень упрощен. Почему мы не можем выполнить такой запрос

```
SELECT `p`.`link`, `p`.`name_ua` name, `p`.`id` as idp
FROM (`projects` p)
WHERE `p`.`idp` = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Потому что idp - это уже алиас p.id, т.е. вы пытаетесь обратиться к `p`.``p`.`id`` (грубо и приближенно)
2. Потому что для where еще не существует результата работы селекта. Этот результат появляется ПОСЛЕ того как отработают события where. 
   Если вы хотите воспользоваться п.1, напишите

   SELECT `p`.`link`, `p`.`name_ua` name, `p`.`id` as idp
   FROM (`projects` p)
   HAVING `idp` = 10